# Is there Adventurers League play in Central America?

Tags: dnd-adventurers-league

Although (cited for comparison) Paizo's website for the [Pathfinder Society](http://paizo.com/pathfinderSociety/about/regionalCoordinators) quickly revealed no organized play between Tijuana and Buenos Aires, the [Wizards website](http://dnd.wizards.com/playevents/organized-play) is extremely Anglocentric. 
I am surprised WOTC does not seek the Latin American market.

Their search engine just flat fails when I enter postal codes for Panama, Belize, Mexico City, Rio, BA, et al. (choosing the appropriate language for each from the bottom right corner, and searching on Mexico City, Rio, and BA just because I could not believe Wizards didn't have organized play listings there). Also, I am not able to find Wizards sites in .ar, .br, .bz, ,mx, or .pa.

Is there Wizards-sanctioned organized D&D play in Central America?

If so, how do I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There Currently is No Organized Play in Central America

It's difficult to prove a negative (that D&D organized play doesn't exist in Central America).  However, I don't think that it does.

I searched for "Belize" on [locator.wizards.com](http://locator.wizards.com) and was quickly able to find many locations offering organized play for other products, mostly MTG.  This shows two things: that the search feature works in Central America and that Wizards does have organized play there.  However, there are no D&D organized play events/locations listed.

Additionally, in the [Adventure League wiki](http://dndadventurersleague.org/sage/index.php?title=Administrators#Latin_America) there are no Local Coordinators assigned to Central America.  A single Regional Coordinator handles everything south of the US border.  At the time of writing, Wizards has Coordinators in Brazil, Costa Rica, and Chile.

### But There Can Be

WoTC does support organized play in Central America.  If you love to play D&D and are interested in Adventure League, contact your [Regional Coordinator](http://dndadventurersleague.org/sage/index.php?title=Administrators#Latin_America) and start playing!

Comment: Planning for retirement,  must have D20 where I retire to.  Not in Central America now.

Comment: ummm...Costa Rica is in Central America

Comment: @mdrichey Agreed. The question was asked in 2015 though, so the answer is about that time. It's not clear to me if the answer should be updated to be more current, or if a new question should be asked about the current state of organized play.